# Is there a command-line application that combines SSH and SFTP?

Tags: ssh, command-line, remote, sftp

When I'm working on some remote host via SSH, I often need to upload or download files.  With my current setup, I need to switch to another terminal and conjure up `rsync` or `sftp`, which can be a pain if the target host isn't registered in DNS (need to copy+paste IP address) or if I'm working in a directory a few levels down (need to re-type the whole path).

Is there a command-line tool that combines SSH and SFTP?  Ideally, it would start a remote shell like normal SSH does but at the press of some key combination, it would switch to an SFTP prompt allowing me to up- download files from the directory the shell is currently in.

Comment: You may want to have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440524/ssh-a-way-to-transfer-files-without-opening-a-separate-sftp-session

Answer (score -1):

You want `rsync`.  You can transfer files from the local or remote machine.

```
?> rsync -avz user@host.ip:/path/to/remote/path path/to/local
```